# what is the meaning of the phrase 'vaccine effort'

Tags: headlinese

'Biden Seeks to Revive Vaccine Effort With New Rules and Incentives' - what is the meaning of the phrase 'vaccine effort' in this sentence3?

Answer (score 3):

It is shorthand for "effort to make people choose to get the COVID-19 vaccine." You will see sich shorthand all the time in headlines.

Comment: As well as manager-speak.

Comment: thanks so much.Can you teach me some more with examples and structure as well